# removing square brackets, double quotes from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have Array Array1

```
Array1=[
"fish.jpg",
"animal.jpg",
"tree.jpg"]
```

I want to store them in my excel but problem is they are coming with square brackets and double quotes

```
["Fish.jpg","animal.jpg","tree.jpg"]
```

So my excel cell look like this

```
name  |         data                          | owner
jpg   |  ["Fish.jpg","animal.jpg","tree.jpg"] | Vikas
```

I want them as single output only they separated by comma(,) as i want to store them in single cell in excel

```
fish.jpg, animal.jpg,tree.jpg
```

so my excel will look like this

- tried to do like this

```
let removedData= Array1.replaceAll("[""]");
```

but got no success

```
name  |         data                   | owner
jpg   |  fish.jpg, animal.jpg,tree.jpg | Vikas
```

Note here name,data,owner are one cell title

Comment: `Array1.join(", ")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that arrays of strings have `[]` or `"` in them (they don't), it's that something is converting them to string by using `JSON.stringify` or similar. (If it were just using `toString`, there wouldn't be `"` in the result.)

Instead, convert to string on purpose. Arrays have a [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to join all of their entries (converted to string if necessary) into a single string using the delimiter you provide:

```
value = yourArray.join(", ");
```